# Matrix notation (sigma of matrix) (refer to a number in matrix)

Tags: matrices, notation

If I define a matrix to be equal to x, may I then refer to a specific number in the matrix by index like so:

$$x=\begin{bmatrix}0,01\\0,05\\0,30\end{bmatrix}~~~~x_1+x_2=0,06$$

---

Also, can you do the following?

$$\sum \begin{bmatrix}0,01\\0,05\\0,30\end{bmatrix}=0,36$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can refer specific entries in matrix, for example

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
in here $a_{11} = 1$,  $a_{22} = 5$, $a_{31} = 7$

In general the notation is $a_{ij}$ where the first subscript is the row number and the second is the column number.

---

If you want to sum all the elements in a column 1 you can do

$\sum_{i = 1}^n a_{i1}$
where n is the number of elements in first column.

And for j:th column it's
$\sum_{i = 1}^n a_{ij}$
where n is the number of elements in j:th column.

For rows you just sum through the columns instead of rows, and if you want to sum all elements of the matrix the sum is

$\sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^k a_{ij}$ where the n is number of rows and k is number of columns.

I hope this helps, this is my first answer on stackexchange.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are not allowed to put a sigma symbol in front of a matrix? You will have to denote the start and value as you did, or what?

Comment: No it's not acceptable to put sigma in front of matrix, you need to sum through all the elements.

Comment: @ user595846 Is it requred it denote the column index if it's a one dimension matrix? In my question I defined x as a one dimensional matrix, was it correct to say: "x_1 + x_2" or should I have said: "x_11 + x_21" ?

Comment: @RyanCameron Yes it is required to denote the column aswell if it is an matrix (even on the one dimensional case), even though I would personally represent matrix with just one column or row as an vector.